# How do I figure out the brand and type of an SD-card on the commandline?

Tags: sd-card, remote, terminal

How do I figure out the brand and type of an SD-card remotely on the commandline via SSH? I so far tried:

- `fdisk -l /dev/mmcblk0`
- `gdisk -l /dev/mmcblk0`
- `dmesg | fgrep -i mmc` (the boot entries were already rotated out of the ring buffer)
- `zfgrep -i mmc /var/log/syslog* /var/log/kern.log*`
- `smartctl --info /dev/mmcblk0` (resulted in `/dev/mmcblk0: Unable to detect device type`)
- `lshw -C storage`
- `file -s /dev/mmcblk0`
- `cfdisk /dev/mmcblk0`
- `cgdisk /dev/mmcblk0`

Context: After having had to replace SD-cards in two of a bunch of remotely deployed Raspberry Pis (LoRaWAN gateways) which were not initially installed by myself, I want to figure out if the remaining, still running Pis have the same type of SD-card or by chance a different brand and/or type.

A bit of information I figured out, but I didn't find a mapping to brand or type, i.e. something that I can correlate with what I can see from the outside of the two broken SD-cards:

```
# cat /sys/block/mmcblk0/device/name 
SU04G

# cat /sys/block/mmcblk0/device/name 
SS08G

# cat /sys/block/mmcblk0/device/name 
ACLCE

# cat /sys/block/mmcblk0/device/name 
SL16G
```

So they seem to be different (the numbers before `G`—where present—correlate with the size), but are they also different manufacturers/series?

At least this always looks the same on all of the four Raspberry Pis from which the four different `name` contents above were taken:

```
# cat /sys/block/mmcblk0/device/oemid 
0x5344
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some data, as you mentioned, is in `/sys/block/mmcblk0/device`. There's a tool called `mmc` in the `mmc-utils` package that can read/decode several of the values in that directory. For instance:

```sh
$ mmc csd read /sys/block/mmcblk0/device
type: 'SD'
card classes: 10 switch, 8 application specific, 4 block write, 2 block read, 0 basic, 
capacity: 14.76Gbyte (15847653376 bytes, 30952448 sectors, 512 bytes each)

$ mmc scr read /sys/block/mmcblk0/device
type: 'SD'
version: SD 3.0x
bus widths: 4bit, 1bit, 

$ mmc cid read /sys/block/mmcblk0/device
type: 'SD'
manufacturer: 'SanDisk' 'SD'
product: 'SS16G' 8.0
serial: 0x95554991
manfacturing date: 2017 jun
```

You can also pass `-v` to any of those commands to get lower-level details on how the data was parsed.

Unfortunately, I haven't figured out if any of the other functionality works on regular SD/MMC cards, or just eMMC. e.g. I can't get `sudo mmc extcsd read /dev/mmcblk0` to work on my Pi. But, with your mention of sysfs I was able to get the tool to parse some of the other data!

Comment: Indeed, thanks! I guess this is the closest we come with this topic. Thanks again!

Comment: `sudo apt install mmc-utils -y && mmc cid read /sys/block/mmcblk0/device` did it for me, thanks

Answer (score 6):

0x5344 from the oemid means SD as in SanDisk. Type is probably not easy; I guess it is their internal name.
Read more at
https://www.cameramemoryspeed.com/sd-memory-card-faq/reading-sd-card-cid-serial-psn-internal-numbers/

Comment: Thanks a lot for that link. That even explains some more of the information I can find in /sys/block/mmcblk0/device/ on Linux. And indeed. hex 0x5344 is "SD" in ASCII. So they're all from SanDisk, but all different models. Now I just need to find a table of there 5-character product names. Oh, and welcome to the site!

Comment: @AxelBeckert: Some more information is [here](https://goughlui.com/2014/01/02/project-read-collect-decode-sd-card-cid-register-data/), and in the "appendix" which follows. There is more data in `/sys/block/mmcblk0/device/csd`, but neither blog helps decode it.

Comment: You can use the `mmc` tool from `mmc-utils` to decode the csd data: `mmc csd read /sys/block/mmcblk0/device` gives something like: `type: 'SD'
card classes: 10 switch, 8 application specific, 4 block write, 2 block read, 0 basic, 
capacity: 14.76Gbyte (15847653376 bytes, 30952448 sectors, 512 bytes each)`